# TFS Post Build script executing twice

Tags: batch-file, tfs, post-build-event

I have a post build batch file being executed after a TFS build. It compiles an Inno Setup script and places the generated exe in a drop folder. It then tries to run that exe and install the application on the server. It runs the exe; however, this hangs the build.

The issue is, it seems to execute it twice. I can see 2 process running for the installer in task manager. If I execute the batch file manually, there are no issues - it's only when TFS executes it, I run into this problem.

**Post Build Batch File**

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5"
iscc "%scriptDir%\Script.iss"
cd "C:\Deployment"
start Installer.exe /VERYSILENT
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Scratching my head with this.

Comment: Do you have it configured as a post-build action in the project file, as well?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No, it's only in the build definition.

Comment: A word of advice (this isn't answer-worthy, since it doesn't solve your specific issue): You're overextending build. Build should **just** build your software and get it into an installable state. Once you have binaries, actually installing them on a remote server is in the domain of a release management solution. Overextending build just creates pain and misery down the line.

Comment: You are probably right. The reason I am looking at this approach is purely for CI purposes. The plan is to kick off automated UI tests once the latest version of the application has been installed. Technically, I could simply use the files in the bin folder from the TFS build but there is a requirement for the application to be installed. I might have to revisit the requirement but it would be better if I can get it to work this way. Any other ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: Ideally you'd use RM + MTM for this: Build software, release to integration/QA environment, once installation is successful, kick off an MTM test plan that contains your UI tests.

Comment: Agreed especially on setup files.  I would run both the installation (setup) and test from RM or any other deployment tech.

Answer (score 0):

From my findings, the post build script was NOT executing twice.

I believe the issue had something to do with permissions. The build service was being executed via the LocalService account which did not have permission to install the application. I THINK the build service tried to execute the installer but was denied and silently failed (and possibly tried again causing the additional installer process).

Solution: Set the Build Service to run under a different account with the permissions to install applications.